# What happens after rm -rf / on dual boot machine

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub, rm

I was given this machine at work which had Windows on it and I dual booted it with Linux (Ubuntu if matters), and now I'm curious what will happen if I wipe out linux with `sudo rm -rf /` before give the machine back to IT?

I know it will wipe everything out, specially GRUB. So my question really is, will the Windows be accessible in any way after that or would I completely brick the machine? If bricked, will they be able to reformat/repartition it to install a new Windows on it for the next user?

Comment: You would be better off to wipe the Ubuntu partition. This will leave `grub` with Ubuntu in the extended boot list, but it will not boot, of course. You can then boot Windows from the extended list and restore the Windows boot loader using one of several methods, including [these](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/). You can also expand the Windows partition to include the released Ubuntu space.

Comment: By `wipe the Ubuntu partition` you meant using Disk manager of Windows, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can extend the system partition from within Windows itself; if not, use an external boot disc, such as Ubuntu Live. Personally, I prefer to use the latter, as I like `gparted`. But in your case you can delete the Ubuntu partition and repair the boot loader, and possibly extend the Windows partition all within a single boot of Windows.

Comment: It may be simpler to boot with restore factory settings. But in any case I would expect an IT department to replace the whole installation with a fresh disc image, so you would do this only to stop your private files being seen by others when you return the machine.

Comment: @AFH thanks, I'll check out the methods you mentioned earlier. And I'm pretty sure they'll do a full image replacement, but for my own knowledge wanted to know, since I've had only linux and never had a dual boot.